# how to generate header file for JNI in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, compilation, java-native-interface

I need to implement JNI in a servlet. I was able to generate .class file but when
I use javah tool I get this error

> Error: cannot access javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
>
> class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet not found

Comment: We need to see your build environment.